# How to install ant?

Tags: java, netbeans, ant

I want to install ant in my Netbeans. When I search for ant in plug-ins I only see "Ant 1.8.1 documentation plugin." Is it sufficient to run ant?

[image]

Comment: Ant is already installed by NetBeans; it uses it to build projects.

Comment: @Alex I wonder if you click on "Installed" tab there will you see it? ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the Documentation in yous Screenshots says "[...] a supplementary Ant module, adds the Ant manual [...]", so I think its not mandatory.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the comments of your question, Netbeans already comes with Ant by default.
You should see it under the "Installed" tab of the same window.